# Meteor: Manipulate Template Data

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

This is a Meteor/Blaze question.

I have a Mongo collection called Lists, which contains list of postIds, which I would like to query and fill in with data from another collection called Posts.

Schema

```
Posts: [{
   _id: String,
   // post data, I want to access this from a repeated list
}]

Lists: [{
 _id: String,
 posts: [String] // of ids
}]
```

List Template:

```
{{#if posts}}   /// referring to List.posts
<div class="list-posts">
  <ul>
    {{#each posts}}

         // here I would like query for the corresponding Posts data   

    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

I'm not sure how to do this with Meteor. Template Helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution would be to use the popular [`dburles:collection-helpers`](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers) package :

```
Lists.helpers({
  posts: function(){
    return Posts.find({
      _id: {
        // I suggest renaming your Lists.posts field to Lists.postIds.
        $in: this.postsIds
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Then you'll have to make sure the corresponding posts are published along with your lists, and you'll be able to use `{{#each posts}}` just like in your pseudo-code.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. Thank you, 'elegant' is the right word for this solution.

Comment: It seems the data remains the same in the template:  `{{#each postIds}}{{this}}{{/each}}` produces a list of ids.

Comment: I suppose I could also use `Template.list_posts.helpers({})` ?

Comment: The advantage of using collection helpers is that you tie the logic to models (it's called fat models paradigm) so these helpers will be available throughout the application, just not in a particular template helper.